# Trying to Use Laravel Superviser

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, supervisord

I have deployed laravel site on server using ssh and after that i want to process mails through queues. And for that I need to install supervisor on server for continuous processing of queues I use

```
apt-get install supervisor
```

Please tell me how should i install supervisor on my go daddy server

[image]

Comment: In your question you mention the use of `apt-get` but in your screenshot I can see you're using `yum` and `rpm`. Those are two separate package management systems. Centos/Fedora/Redhat uses yum/rpm and Ubuntu type systems use apt.

Comment: i tried all including yum apt-get, wget

Comment: What OS is your server?

Comment: its linux. Guys query is still not solved.

Comment: Yeah I guessed it was Linux, what flavour? CentOS, Ubuntu etc.?